# How do we group spark boolean expressions using functions and() and or() in spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark

Let's say, I have some filtering conditions on a data set which looks like like.

`((col1 && col2) || col3)`

or

`(col1 && (col2 || col3))`

How can I express this in **java** spark apis  **and** and **or**.

My question is how to group the expression using Column.and and Column.or functions

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `filter` for this type of filtering, by specifying the columns by the String of their name as argument in `col()` methods.

So for the following input DataFrame `df1` with three columns `first`, `second`, `third`:

```
+-----+------+-----+
|first|second|third|
+-----+------+-----+
| true|  true| true|
| true|  true|false|
| true| false|false|
| true| false| true|
+-----+------+-----+
```

You can use something like this:

```
// Java
df1.filter(col("first").and(col("second")).or(col("third")))

// Scala
df1.filter((col("first") && col("second")) || col("third"))
```

And successfully filter out the third row as seen at the output below:

```
+-----+------+-----+
|first|second|third|
+-----+------+-----+
| true|  true| true|
| true|  true|false|
| true| false| true|
+-----+------+-----+
```

In the same wavelength for your alternate logical expression, you can use something like this:

```
df1.filter(col("col2").or(col("col3")).and(col("col1")))
```

Comment: Hey Coursal. My question is specific to java filter api. the filter function accepts the argument of type "Column". and you cannot do Column && Column in java. the compiler throws the error stating && operation is not supported on type column.

Comment: You can just use the `df1.filter(col("first").and(col("second")).or(col("third")))` part of my answer, you don't have to put both in your code. I just put the solution for both Java and Scala langunage, in case someone comes in here in the future and needs one of those two for their program.

Comment: What would be the java expression if my required boolean expression is (col1 && (col2 || col3)) ?

Comment: I updated the answer for your alternate logical expression

Comment: Yes, My point was that we have to reorder the expression in such a way that the innermost boolean expression. (an expression that should get  evaluated) should be leftmost while writing  in java unlike in scala or python where we can apply parenthesis to specify evaluation order

Comment: This goes all down to how Scala (and Python) is almost functional programming native to the way that handles passing output to a pipeline of commands, in contrary to Java where we are insufferably limited to the structured/OOP way of thing. So yes, I'm afraid reordering the statements is unavoidable in Java. This also has a lot to do with seeing Spark's Java API getting more and more "behind" Scala's with each edition. I even read the documentation yesterday to see that some DataFrame functions in Java get specifically Scala's `Seq` as argument(s).